# Geo program design suggestions using Redis

Tags: database-design, redis, geolocation, geospatial, nosql

I am in the process of learning Redis and am building a geo program for learning purposes. I would like to only use Redis to store the data and am trying to avoid any relational databases. My question is how to best design the database for the program. This is what the how the program goes:

1) I will create millions of random robots around the world which wander so they can have different geo coordinates (some robots can be in the exact same space).

2) Each robot will randomly send a post to the server (every few hours possibly on average) which will contain:
    a) the location of where the robot sent this data from (in either coordinates or geohash depending on the best implementation idea)
    b) some small text

3) I will have a map with all the robots and would like to be able to click on a robot and get this information:
    a) all the posts which were posted nearby the robot I just clicked

4) Due to the fact I will be hosting this on AWS I will need to delete the posts every couple of hours to keep the memory usage low so some type of expiration is mandatory.

My main concern is performance and I am interested in how to design the Redis database.

In a single day (I will work out the math for random posts to do this) about ~500,000,000 posts will be generated.

My Incomplete ideas so far:

**Idea 1**

1) a post would be stored as such:

```
`HSET [Geohash of location] [timestamp] [small text] (<-- the value will be used in a later feature to increment the number of manual modification I make to a post).
```

2) I then would be able to get all the posts near a robot by sending the geohash location he is in. The downfall here is I would also need to include his 8 geohash neighbors which would require 8 more queries. Which is why I am also looking into concept of spatial proximity for this feature.

```
HGETALL [GeoHash Location of robot]
```

This would then return the field ([timestamp]) and value ("0");

3) Expiration of old posts. Since I can't use the EXPIRE command to delete fields from a hashset, I would then need to scan through all the hashset fields periodically and find old timestamps and remove them. Since Redis only allows pattern searching this could will be difficult when all the timestamps are different.

**Idea 2:**

Use Redis-geo (https://matt.sh/redis-geo).

1) To store the posts I would run:

```
geoadd globalSet [posts_long] [posts_lat] "small text";
```

2) To get all the post information for a robot nearby:

```
georadius globalSet [robots_long] [robots_lat] [X] km
```

This would return all posts near the robot within X kms.

3) Then I am now stuck how to remove old posts

Comment: Note that as of v3.2 Redis supports Geosets with the [`GEOADD`](https://redis.io/commands/geoadd) command.

Comment: As systemjack pointed about search- redismodules.com has a search module. It has a random forest module to find nearest neighbours as well.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, lets separate our tasks:

1. We need an index which contain all of our robots, so we can iterate over them
2. Probably we will need to store some generic information about our robot
3. We need to store geo-history for every robot
4. We need to cleanup old data every X

**1**) Lets make ZSET which contain robot ID and his SCORE will be last-activity-timestamp, in future we will be able to delete non-active robots using this index.

`ZADD ZSET:ROBOTS <timestamp> robot:17`

or event better just `17` without `robot:` because of redis will store integers as 4 bytes in the RAM.

**2**) Lets store our robot generic info in HSET

`HSET HSET:ROBOT:17 name "Best robot ever #17" model "Terminator T-800"`

**3**) Generally we can use several ways to store it, for example we can take regular ZSET using multi dimensional indexes technique ([Multi dimensional indexes](https://redis.io/topics/indexes#multi-dimensional-indexes)), but it very complicated to understand, so lets use simpler redis GEO

```
      GEOADD GEO:ROBOT:17 13.361389 38.115556 "<timestamp>:<message-data>"
```

Internally GEO use regular ZSET, so we can easily iterate over it by `ZRANGE or ZRANGEBYSCORE commands`.

And of course we can use GEO commands like GEORADIUS for our needs.

**4**) The cleanup process. I suggest to clean-up by time, but you can make it in same way by number of entries, just use `ZRANGE` instead `ZRANGEBYSCORE`

Lets find all of our non active robots that was non active at least a week.

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE ZSET:ROBOTS -inf <timestamp-of-week-before>
```

Now we need to iterate over those ID's and remove un-needed HSET, GEO keys and remove it from our `index`

```
ZREM ZSET:ROBOTS 17
DEL HSET:ROBOT:17
DEL GEO:ROBOT:17
```

Now we need to remove only old GEO-history entries, as I said above GEO in redis is a regular ZSET under the hood, so lets use ZRANGE

```
ZRANGE GEO:ROBOT:17 0 -1
```

We will get list of entries, but it will be sorted strange because of GEO, each `score` will be `GEO location`.

Our entries formatted as ":" so we can use `split(':')` and compare timestamp, if it to old we remove it. For example our timestamp is `12345678` and message is `hello`

```
ZDEL GEO:ROBOT:17 1234567:hello
```

P.S. I highly recommend you to read this awesome article about ZSET's in [redis](https://redis.io/topics/indexes)

In short: Redis sorting items not only by score but by key name too, this means that entries with same score will be sorted alphabetical, which is very useful!

```
ZADD key 0 ccc 0 bbb 0 aaa
ZRANGE key 0 -1
```

will return you sorted set:

```
 1. "aaa"
 2. "bbb"
 3. "ccc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you an idea base on how i understood your problem:

Instead of storing values in hash, simply store everything in redis.
Construct the key as GeoLocation:[Geohash location of robot]:1[indicating the number of post, this will keep on incrementing whenever a new request comes]:timestamp and value will be the timestamp.
Similarly for small text  GeoLocation:[Geohash location of robot]:1[indicating the number of post]:smallText. 
Use set expire to set the values and set the expire time as your wish.

Ex: setex GeoLocation:12.31939:1:timestamp 1432423232 (timestamp) 14400 (4 hrs)
    setex GeoLocation:12.31939:1:smalltext ronaldo 14400

Thus you will get any number of posts from all robots with a distinct key to access and setting expire has also become easy.

Now to get all the info posted by a particular robot, use keys GeoLocation:(location of particular robot):* and get values of each.

In this way you don't need to scan through all the keys in redis. You will get the info relatively quicker and keys are expired by it's own.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I don't understand though how to retrieve the keys. To use something like GeoLocation:(location of particular robot):* wouldn't I need to use the SCAN command to be able to pattern match? If so isn't this command O(N) so wouldn't I then have to scan through all the keys in Redis?

Comment: let me give u an idea in java (jedis)

Set <String> keys=jedis.keys("GeoLocation:"+(location of robot)+"*");
this will return all keys matching for a particular robot.

Then loop through that set to get the posts and TimeStamp u need.

This will be O(M) instead of O(N). As we are only looping throught the keys that matches for a particular robot.

And thus u will recieve all the posts by a particular robot.

Comment: The purpose is to try to get all the posts which were made by other robots near the robot's location, not posts made by a that specific robot.

Comment: find the location of robots near that specific one and do the same process as mentioned above.

Comment: I am sorry I am not understanding what you mean. Say I have a robot at geohash ABCDE. I now want to get all the posts around him. So you are saying to use the Keys command with a wildcard to match the pattern. The keys command is O(N) http://redis.io/commands/KEYS. If you could maybe write jedis from start to finish maybe I could have a better picture of what you mean and are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

One idea I take away from the description is that you'll know the current location of a given "robot" and you'd like to find other mobile users near it in real time, but you'd also like some bit of historical location information.

I like to think of redis as exposing raw building blocks for making a higher level database. With that in mind you realize you need to build and maintain your own higher level database features like indexes, etc.

Since this type of data will primarily be accessed when you have a specific robot in mind, I'd recommend storing the location history and metadata for a bot in a key based on the bot's unique identifier and not its location.

Then maintain it's relative location (or any other grouping) to others by managing its ID in sets or hashes that group bots in a given location. You can use multiple sets or nested data structures for a sort of level of detail capability.

Keep your data integrity by updating the bot record and the location info as part of a redis [transaction](http://redis.io/topics/transactions). Use [pipelining](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining) for efficiency.

You don't need to use [expire](http://redis.io/commands/expire) for old posts as you can manage your database size by limiting the count of historical entries in the bot's main record. When you go to update a bot, just do some kind of cleanup operation on it when it gets over a certain length (llen, slen, hlen, etc.) to give you a predictable/adjustable aggregate data size.

If there's any hope what you're doing might become production I highly recommend considering [partitioning](http://redis.io/topics/partitioning) out of the gate. Any level of success will require it so might as well do it up front. Trust me. For this case I'd partition functionally (location vs. robot state...different databases on different replication groups) as well as by key (hash or whatever...to break down your 500M into reasonable chunks).

Partitioning makes transactions tough but for your use case I doubt that's a deal breaker. Using [redis messaging](http://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush) in conjunction with transactions can allow you to keep your integrity by executing various updates programatically.

Finally, I'd consider something besides redis (elasticache in your case I'm assuming). In the spectrum of support for concurrency and ability to do complex queries, redis is great for the former. For that reason it's perfect for keeping track of sessions or similar state.

You'll require a lot of concurrency but it's mostly appending and not updates. So not like an evolving state machine. And you need at least some ability to search.

If you need to relate objects to each other (queries), be able to support analytics, etc., with 500M users you'd be able to afford a big redshift cluster, dynamo or similar. Could put kinesis in front to help with concurrency by batching small messages up for bulk loading. Both redshift and dynamo benefit from special loading paths from kinesis.

Definitely want to stay away from RDS, but there's other options that would be simpler to implement and would help you avoid that inevitable day when you have to iterate your redis cluster (for which you'd use [scan](http://redis.io/commands/scan) obviously).

(Old post I know but interesting question and the answer applies to lots of situations.)